# Why this Hibernate Relation isn't working?

Tags: java, hibernate

I try to Connect Pizzas and Ingredients in a n:m relation while all Pizzas have Ingredients as an Attribute List of Ingredients. But in the Relationstable when I create a new Pizza and try to commit there is an Error with the PizzaID in the Relationtable.

The relational Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Pizza_Ingredience_Relation` (
  `PizzaID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `IngredientID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Volume_Unit` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PizzaID`,`IngredientID`),
  KEY `FKc58en2gx5a8n1swmu9tda345` (`IngredientID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_IngredienceId` FOREIGN KEY (`IngredientID`) REFERENCES `Zutatenliste` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKc58en2gx5a8n1swmu9tda345` FOREIGN KEY (`IngredientID`) REFERENCES `Zutatenliste` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKhghfxg8raskdydyu8o8msxtfn` FOREIGN KEY (`PizzaID`) REFERENCES `Pizza` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

The Ingredient Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Zutatenliste` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

The Pizza Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Pizza` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `PreisKlein` double NOT NULL,
  `PreisMittel` double NOT NULL,
  `PreisGroß` double NOT NULL,
  `PreisFamilie` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

I have two hibernate Entitites, one is a Pizza Entitiy and one the Ingredient Entitiy:

```
package Model.PizzenDB.SQLConnectionClasses.MySQL;

import Model.PizzenDB.Pizza;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionId;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Where;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Pizza")
public class MySQLPizzaHibernateEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "PreisKlein")
    private double smallPrice;
    @Column(name = "PreisMittel")
    private double middlePrice;
    @Column(name = "PreisGroß")
    private double bigPrice;
    @Column(name = "PreisFamilie")
    private double familyPrice;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(
            name = "Pizza_Ingredience_Relation",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PizzaID",          referencedColumnName = "ID") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "IngredientID") }
    )
    private Set<MySQLIngredientWithAmountHibernateEntity> ingredience;

    public MySQLPizzaHibernateEntity(String name, double smallPrice,            double middlePrice, double bigPrice, double familyPrice) {
        this.name = name;
        this.smallPrice = smallPrice;
        this.middlePrice = middlePrice;
        this.bigPrice = bigPrice;
        this.familyPrice = familyPrice;
    }

    public MySQLPizzaHibernateEntity() {
    }



}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Zutatenliste")
@SecondaryTable(name = "Pizza_Ingredience_Relation", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "IngredientID", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
public class MySQLIngredientWithAmountHibernateEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;
    @Column(table = "Pizza_Ingredience_Relation", name="Amount")
    private int amount;
    @Column(table = "Pizza_Ingredience_Relation", name = "Volume_Unit")
    private char unit;

    public MySQLIngredientWithAmountHibernateEntity(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public MySQLIngredientWithAmountHibernateEntity() {
        this("");
    }
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
20:41:45 [main] [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] ERROR - Field 'PizzaID' doesn't have a default value
20:41:45 [main] [org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl] ERROR - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement]
```

I'm not sure what is wrong in detail I guess it has todo with the PizzaID Foreign Key and that it isn't set properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many to many relationship, you are using middle table with extra columns and you need Embeddable key for that which would comprise of Pizza and Ingredient object (names shortened). Something like:

```
@Embeddable
public class PizzaIngredientPk {
    private MySQLPizzaHibernateEntity pizza;
    private MySQLIngredientWithAmountHibernateEntity ingredient;

    @ManyToOne
    public MySQLPizzaHibernateEntity getPizza() {
        return pizza;
    }
    public void setPizza(MySQLPizzaHibernateEntity pizza) {
        this.pizza = pizza;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    public MySQLIngredientWithAmountHibernateEntity getIngredient() {
        return ingredient;
    }
    public void setIngredientID(MySQLIngredientWithAmountHibernateEntity ingredient) {
        this.ingredient = ingredient;
    }
}
```

Then this would act as Embedded Key in MySQLIngredientWithAmountHibernateEntity as

```
    @EmbeddedId
    PizzaIngredientPk pk = new PizzaIngredientPk();
```

But this won't work with Secondarytable which is used for one-to-one relationship. @SecondaryTable requires mapping to be with a primary key but in this case Embedded ID would become PK. In fact, you have flaw in your design. You are trying to make one side of your many to many relationship as one-to-one.

As per JPA docs There must be only one EmbeddedId annotation and no Id annotation when the EmbeddedId annotation is used.

Comment: Thank you that was the correct way but I added ```@JoinColumn(name = "RelationTableName", insertable = false, updatable = false)``` because it isn't allowed that the related Tables are updated (Idk if it possible I don't tried)

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify to Hibernate automatically produce primary keys. Put this annotation above your Id fields and re-create your database.

`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

See: https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-use-auto-incremented-column-primary-key/